# (Xamarin Forms) How do I get the BasePageType of my Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a pages called FirstMainPage and SecondMainPage which both inherit from MasterDetailPage.  In my App.cs I do a MainPage.GetType it will return the Type FirstMainPage or SecondMainPage (or something else).  How do I get the BasePageType so it returns MasterDetailPage if the page inherits from MasterDetailPage?

I want to be able to cast the MainPage to MasterDetailPage so I can access the MasterDetailPage.Master if it is a MasterDetailPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `is` test on your `Page` to determine is it is a master-detail:

```
if (MainPage is MasterDetailPage) 
{
  var master = (MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Master;
}
```

Ref: [is (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)